# Animate a perspective transformation in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, transform

I need to animate a card, which moves under a scanner:

Start picture:
[image: Start screen]
*left: the scanner. right: the card*

End picture:
[image: End Screen]
*the card moves under the scanner. the scanner won't move*

Now I tried to animate this with the timeline animation.
Just insert both states and press on the tweening-button.
The problem is, that the card will be transformed from the beginning, and not while the card moves.

How do I achieve my objective?
I only have Illustrator & Photoshop, and at the end I need an animated .gif.

Comment: I would suggest using After Effects

Comment: @Darth_Vader: I never used it and I would need to download it and only use the 30 days free version...

Comment: what version photoshop are you using?

Comment: 2014.0.0 20140508.r.58

Comment: 2014 should be the creative cloud..  you pay a subscription so you wouldn't have a 30 day trial.

Comment: I've the Photography-CC... I asked my boss if it's possible to get the full package. I'll see. But thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop only allows you to keyframe the position, opacity, and style elements of a layer. If you're trying to animate the card from a standing position to a laying flat position (and you don't have access to any other software outside of Photoshop or Illustrator); you will need to create separate states of the image and then hide/show them in order to create a persistence of vision effect.

Comment: So like a classic gif. Just create all the frames by hand and put them together?

Comment: Correct. Is it critical to your project that you show the transition from standing to lying flat? I think having the card appear facing up the entire time would still get across the message to the user.

Comment: The final illustration will feature a scanner-graphic. So it would look strange. But thanks for your answer, I'll create a simple moving transition without transforming, and when there is still time left, I'll do the old fashioned way.